# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException while fetching data from multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am getting **org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException** exception while fetching data from multiple tables in getMenusByRole. My query is correct and giving expected result on database. 
Following is code snippet-

UserDaoImpl.java

```
package com.msoft.crm.daos;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map; 

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;   
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSInput;    
import com.msoft.crm.entities.Users;

@Repository("UserDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {   
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;        
    public String original,recipientAddress,firstName,userName;
    @Override
    public List<Users> getAllUsers() {                  
        return new ArrayList<Users>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> validateLogin(String username, String password) {            
        String hql = "from Users u where u.username = :p_username and u.userPassword = :p_password";            
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("p_username", username);
        q.setParameter("p_password", password);         
        List<Users> users = q.getResultList();          
        System.out.println("users : " + users);         
        return users;

    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> getMenusByRole(long userId) {

        String hql = " select ur.role_id ,ur.role_name ,ur.speciality ,ms.section_id ,ms.section_name ,ms.section_position ,"
                + "ms.section_icon ,mi.menu_id ,mi.menu_name ,mi.menu_action ,mi.menu_position ,mi.parent_menu_id "
                + "from MenuPrivileges mp inner join UserRoles ur on mp.role_id = ur.role_id "
                + "inner join MenuItems mi on mp.menu_id = mi.menu_id " 
                + "inner join MenuSections ms on mi.section_id = ms.section_id "
                + "where mi.active_ind  = '1' and mp.visible_ind = '1' " 
                + "and mp.role_id = (select role_id from crm_users where user_id = :user_id) order by ms.section_position asc";

        Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("user_id", userId);
        List<Users> l = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("l : " + l);
        return l;   
    }       

}
```

MenuPrivileges.java

```
package com.msoft.crm.entities;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name="crm_menu_privileges")
public class MenuPrivileges {

    @Id
    @Column
    private int role_id;
    @Column
    private int menu_id;
    @Column
    private String visible_ind;

    public MenuPrivileges() {
        this(0,0,"");
    }
    public MenuPrivileges(int role_id, int menu_id, String visible_ind) {
        this.role_id = role_id;
        this.menu_id = menu_id;
        this.visible_ind = visible_ind;
    }
    //getter and setter
}
```

UserRoles.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="crm_user_roles")
public class UserRoles {

@Id
@Column
private int role_id;     
@Column
private String role_name;
@Column
private String speciality;

// getters and setters
}
```

MenuItems.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="crm_menu_items")
public class MenuItems {

    @Id
    @Column
    private int section_id;  
    @Column
    private int menu_id;     
    @Column
    private String menu_name;    
    @Column
    private String menu_desc;    
    @Column
    private String menu_action;  
    @Column
    private int menu_position;   
    @Column
    private int parent_menu_id;  
    @Column
    private String active_ind;

    // getter and setter
    }
```

MenuSections.javv

```
@Entity
@Table(name="crm_menu_sections")
public class MenuSections {

    @Id
    @Column
    private int id_pk;  
    @Column
    private int section_id;  
    @Column
    private String section_name;     
    @Column
    private String section_desc;     
    @Column
    private String section_icon;
    @Column
    private int section_position;
    //getter and setter
    }
```

Following is my stacktrace where both queries are working but getting above mentioned exception for getMenuByRole.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        users0_.user_id as user_id1_5_,
        users0_.aadhar_no as aadhar_n2_5_,
        users0_.active_ind as active_i3_5_,
        users0_.created_by_user_id as created_4_5_,
        users0_.created_date_time as created_5_5_,
        users0_.email as email6_5_,
        users0_.fname as fname7_5_,
        users0_.lname as lname8_5_,
        users0_.login_status as login_st9_5_,
        users0_.mname as mname10_5_,
        users0_.mobile as mobile11_5_,
        users0_.photo as photo12_5_,
        users0_.role_id as role_id13_5_,
        users0_.password as passwor14_5_,
        users0_.username as usernam15_5_ 
    from
        crm_users users0_ 
    where
        users0_.username=? 
        and users0_.password=?
users : [Users [userId=3, roleId=1, sectionId=0, sectionPosition=0, menuId=0, menuPosition=0, parentMenuId=0, specialityId=0, username=shirin, activeInd=1, loginStatus=1, roleName=null, speciality=null, sectionName=null, sectionIcon=null, menuName=null, menuAction=null, firstName=yogiraj, lastName=kulkarni, mobileNumber=9699999999, middleName=, emailAddress=yogirajk@msoft.co.in, aadhaarNumber=123456987456, profileImg=data:image/jpeg;base64,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, fullName=null, userPassword=e7202d28c87440d38bd5bf4ff37c7fcc, createdBy=1, createdDate=2017-06-14 11:16:12.0]]
active ind(service):1
In get menus role user id : 3
Hibernate: 
    select
        ur.role_id ,
        ur.role_name ,
        ur.speciality ,
        ms.section_id ,
        ms.section_name ,
        ms.section_position ,
        ms.section_icon ,
        mi.menu_id ,
        mi.menu_name ,
        mi.menu_action ,
        mi.menu_position ,
        mi.parent_menu_id 
    from
        MenuPrivileges mp 
    inner join
        UserRoles ur 
            on mp.role_id = ur.role_id 
    inner join
        MenuItems mi 
            on mp.menu_id = mi.menu_id 
    inner join
        MenuSections ms 
            on mi.section_id = ms.section_id 
    where
        mi.active_ind  = '1' 
        and mp.visible_ind = '1' 
        and mp.role_id = (
            select
                role_id 
            from
                crm_users 
            where
                user_id = ?
        ) 
    order by
        ms.section_position asc
2017-11-07 10:27:47.364  WARN 3116 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2017-11-07 10:27:47.364 ERROR 3116 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn:143322) Table 'crm_application.MenuPrivileges' doesn't exist
Query is:  select ur.role_id ,ur.role_name ,ur.speciality ,ms.section_id ,ms.section_name ,ms.section_position ,ms.section_icon ,mi.menu_id ,mi.menu_name ,mi.menu_action ,mi.menu_position ,mi.parent_menu_id from MenuPrivileges mp inner join UserRoles ur on mp.role_id = ur.role_id inner join MenuItems mi on mp.menu_id = mi.menu_id inner join MenuSections ms on mi.section_id = ms.section_id where mi.active_ind  = '1' and mp.visible_ind = '1' and mp.role_id = (select role_id from crm_users where user_id = ?) order by ms.section_position asc, parameters [3]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.msoft.crm.daos.UserDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$337e38b5.getMenusByRole(<generated>)
    at com.msoft.crm.services.UserService.validateLogin(UserService.java:44)
    at com.msoft.crm.controllers.LoginController.validateLogin(LoginController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    at com.msoft.crm.daos.UserDaoImpl.getMenusByRole(UserDaoImpl.java:115)
    at com.msoft.crm.daos.UserDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$da03a52e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:143322) Table 'crm_application.MenuPrivileges' doesn't exist
Query is:  select ur.role_id ,ur.role_name ,ur.speciality ,ms.section_id ,ms.section_name ,ms.section_position ,ms.section_icon ,mi.menu_id ,mi.menu_name ,mi.menu_action ,mi.menu_position ,mi.parent_menu_id from MenuPrivileges mp inner join UserRoles ur on mp.role_id = ur.role_id inner join MenuItems mi on mp.menu_id = mi.menu_id inner join MenuSections ms on mi.section_id = ms.section_id where mi.active_ind  = '1' and mp.visible_ind = '1' and mp.role_id = (select role_id from crm_users where user_id = ?) order by ms.section_position asc, parameters [3]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:139)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:101)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.ExceptionMapper.throwAndLogException(ExceptionMapper.java:77)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MariaDbStatement.java:226)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:233)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: Table 'crm_application.MenuPrivileges' doesn't exist
Query is:  select ur.role_id ,ur.role_name ,ur.speciality ,ms.section_id ,ms.section_name ,ms.section_position ,ms.section_icon ,mi.menu_id ,mi.menu_name ,mi.menu_action ,mi.menu_position ,mi.parent_menu_id from MenuPrivileges mp inner join UserRoles ur on mp.role_id = ur.role_id inner join MenuItems mi on mp.menu_id = mi.menu_id inner join MenuSections ms on mi.section_id = ms.section_id where mi.active_ind  = '1' and mp.visible_ind = '1' and mp.role_id = (select role_id from crm_users where user_id = ?) order by ms.section_position asc, parameters [3]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1144)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1076)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1031)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:203)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(MariaDbClientPreparedStatement.java:224)
    ... 88 more

2017-11-07 10:27:47.383 ERROR 3116 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

Comment: The exception message is clear: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:143322) Table 'crm_application.MenuPrivileges' doesn't exist` So check if the table exists

Comment: yes table exist in database.

Answer (score 0):

In your `getMenusByRole` you are using plain SQL and not HSQL. So your table names should be `crm_menu_privileges`, `crm_user_roles` and so on.

Comment: I changed entity class names to table names but I am getting another exception as 'java.lang.ClassCastException'

Comment: I dont like Hibernate and dont use it. I always prever to write SQL in SQL as SQL was meant to be used for interacting with RDBMS. All these HSQL is a pain. For complex queries where HSQL makes it difficult, you can use SQL. But then SQL written in form of string concatenation is difficult to follow. Thats why I prefer MyBatis :)

Comment: For the exception, please post the stacktrace in your original post. Without stacktrace we cannot say the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the native query, the getResultSet() method will not return an object of User class. The other reason is HQL has not been invoked in this query and it will not be able to map the entities by its own.

In your case, the getResultSet() will return an array of Object as follows:

```
List<Object[]> l = q.getResultList();
```

And then you have to extract each element from this returned array.

For example, the Object[0] will return ur.role_id and Object[1] will return ur.role_name and so on as specified in your query.

Comment: Can that result be converted to list?

Comment: You have to manually do that. Else change you entity classes and implement joins, so that you can use hql in your queries.